# Posting or displaying multiple strings in messagebox c++

Tags: c++, string, messagebox

I want to display multiple strings in different lines in a messagebox in c++.
I want it to show as:

```
Number of Words: 10
Number of Sentences: 5
Number of Digits: 2
Number of Upper Case Characters:5
```

How Do i do it?
MessageBox( NULL, ***HERE***,"CSE 3120 - Term Project", MB_OK |  MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);

instead of here, all these string should go.. I just dont know how to show them, and all the numbers are stored in variables.

any idea?
Thanks in advance, guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
Number of Words: 10
Number of Sentences: 5
Number of Digits: 2
Number of Upper Case Characters:5    

char text[128];
sprintf(text, "Number of Words: %d", noOfWords);
sprintf(text, "Number of Sentences: %d", noOfSentences);
sprintf(text, "Number of Digits: %d", noOfDigits);
sprintf(text, "Number of Upper Case: %d", noOfUCase);
MessageBox(NULL, text, "", MB_OK);
```

Comment: Ya, I figured that out. Thanks a lot.